# How to delete all the "*.exe" files which is 132kb

Tags: fedora, find, malware

My external hard disk got a windows virus which makes lots of `filename.exe` copies of 132.6 kb.

When I write `find . -type f -name "*.exe"` it founds thousands of .exe files and only 100 or 200 of them are my files.

Do you know a smart way to extract virus files and delete all at once without losing my data?

Comment: If you can predict the range where your file might be (or equivalently the bad ones) use `-size` as something like `find . -type f -name '*.exe' -size +20M`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` with `-size` option:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.exe' -size 133k
```

or

```
find . -type f -iname '*.exe' -size 135783c
```

after you confirm those are bad files, you can add `-delete` option to the command to delete those files.

from `man find`:

> ```
>    -size n[cwbkMG]
>           File uses n units of space, rounding up.  The following suffixes can be used:
>
>           `b'    for 512-byte blocks (this is the default if no suffix is used)
>
>           `c'    for bytes
>
>           `w'    for two-byte words
>
>           `k'    for Kibibytes (KiB, units of 1024 bytes)
>
>           `M'    for Mebibytes (MiB, units of 1024 * 1024 = 1048576 bytes)
>
>           `G'    for Gibibytes (GiB, units of 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 1073741824 bytes)
>
>           The size does not count indirect blocks, but it does count blocks in sparse files that are not  actu‐
>           ally allocated.  Bear in mind that the `%k' and `%b' format specifiers of -printf handle sparse files
>           differently.  The `b' suffix always denotes 512-byte blocks and never 1024-byte blocks, which is dif‐
>           ferent to the behaviour of -ls.
>
>           The  +  and  -  prefixes signify greater than and less than, as usual; i.e., an exact size of n units
>           does not match.  Bear in mind that the size is rounded up to the next unit. Therefore  -size  -1M  is
>           not  equivalent  to  -size  -1048576c.  The former only matches empty files, the latter matches files
>           from 0 to 1,048,575 bytes.
> ```

Comment: Thanks! handled it using "sudo find . -type f -name "*.exe" -size +132607c -size -132609c -exec rm -rf {} \;"

Answer (score 0):

Done with Python. Tested and worked fine.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re
di=[]
fip=[]
o=re.compile(r'.exe$')
for i,j,k in os.walk('path'):
    di.append(i.strip())
    for q in k:
        fip.append(q.strip())
    
for n in di:
    for g in fip:
        u=os.path.join(n,g)
        if re.search(o,u):  #This step used to verify .exe file"
            if os.path.isfile(u):
                if str(os.stat(u).st_size) == "132":
                    os.remove(u)
```